# Rails: nil error where I am sure the object is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This method increments the ActiveRecord attr_accessible attribute `current_step`:

```
def next_step
  logger.debug "Now at step: " + current_step.inspect
  if (current_step == nil)
    current_step = 0
  end
  current_step = current_step + 1
end
```

At execution of the method, the log shows `Now at step: 0` but the +1 line fails:

```
NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.+):
  app/models/assessment.rb:16:in `next_step'
```

Is it a miracle? Is `current_step` nil or not?

---

EDIT: Thanks fl00r and whitequark for the great answers! Here is what the code was meant to be:

```
def next_step
  current_step ||= 0
  self.current_step += 1
  save
end
```

Comment: I think you should use `current_step.nil?` in your if rather than comparing using `==`

Comment: This feels like method/variable ambiguity (implicit receiver). Assuming `current_step` is an attribute of the model in which `next_step` is defined, what happens if you write `self.current_step` everywhere that you have `current_step`?

Comment: Yes, the attribute and the method are in the same model, sorry for the omission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditionals and loops do not have their own scope in Ruby; and here you have a variable and a method of `self` which possess the same name. In the condition of `if`, the `current_step` method is used, but in its body a local variable is defined, and all future references to the `current_step` will refer to the local variable. The pitfall you've encountered is, even if the `if` body is not executed, the local variable is still defined, and default value of `nil` is assigned to it.

I'll make it more clear by adding `_M` to the identifier when the method is accessed, and `_L`  for the local variable.

```
def next_step
  logger.debug "Now at step: " + current_step_M.inspect
  if (current_step_M == nil)
    current_step_L = 0
  ### this part is implicit:
  # else
  #   current_step_L = nil
  end
  current_step_L = current_step_L + 1
end
```

I'm guessing you was actually trying to do `self.current_step = 0`, which would invoke the setter.

Comment: Enlightening answer! It makes me understand a lot of things (I am new to Ruby)

Answer (score 1):

```
def next_step
  current_step ||= 0
  logger.debug "Now at step: " + current_step.inspect
  current_step += 1
end
```

Comment: Thanks, it does not crash anymore! Somehow, the next time I read `current_step` it is still zero, though...

Comment: here is not enough information about what is `current_step` and what do you mean about `next time` etc. the problem is not about this code, but about something you didn't show.

Comment: You are right! My question is fully answered by those two great answers :-) Even if I have a few more issues to solve on my side, probably unrelated to this question.